# Store the output of (groupby().get_group()) in different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a huge data frame, I want to group it using groupby() and then store the different groups as data frames. Is there a way to do so? I would like to have after the loop data frames with different names containing these groups.  My code gives me one grouped data frame.

```
d=data.groupby(data["Column1"])
KEYS=d.groups.keys()
for k in KEYS: 
   New_dataframe=d.get_group(k)
```

Comment: `grouped_dfs = {k:d for k,d in  data.groupby('Column1')}`?

Comment: save as dictionary: `out = dict(iter(d))` ?

Comment: @QuangHoang I still get one grouped data frame. I want one data frame for each group

Comment: It's a dictionary, you can access each dataframe with `grouped_dfs[name1]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I understand. But I have around 100 groups so I don't want to access each dataframe individually. My problem is I don't know how to access all of these dataframes inside of the loop.